# How to add likes to the top Facebook business pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-timeline

I noticed in the [NYT Facebook business page](https://www.facebook.com/nytimes) that they have the business page's likes posted at the very top of the their timeline profile on the right hand side, and that they are using it to display links to various sections in their website.

How can I get the links to stick to the right hand side of the Facebook Business page like that?

Comment: Some of the business pages I have display it at the top, and others display it at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is one of those magic little boxes of Facebook. For example for me, the likes of the page you mention appears two boxes from the top (because I have friends who are fans of the page). It's most likely that the most used/related info gets pushed right and the recent information gets pushed left, though when there is not enough information the layout reorganizes.

Of course, this is all on the subset of pages I inspect, but this is as best you can get. I really don't believe this is something Facebook is willing to show how it works to prevent users gaming the system.

Summary: Based on the limited information I have, I believe the likes stay on the right and move down based on your friend activity related to the current page.